# Appending value inside nested for loop with if condition is met

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append values inside a nested for loop with if statement. In the script shown below , the first for loop is running the first array which has the element string of "SUM" which is inside filters array. Inside the nested for loop, can i call a condition which will check if "condition === sum" from the outer for loop.  with the if condition i wrote inside the nested for loop, nothing appeared console log, only the outer unnested for loop was visible

```
     var transposeArr = new Array()

        for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
            if(filters[i].$4 === "SUM"){ 
            // This condition works fine however i need to call this inside nested for loop
                console.log("Outer loop : success")
            }
           
                for(let a = 0; a < filters[i].$9.length;a++){ 
                    if(!transposeArr[a]) transposeArr[a] = [''];
                    if(filters[i].$4 === "SUM"){
                        // Append data to array 
                        console.log("inner loop : success")
                        transposeArr[a][i] = "Success";
                    } else {
                        transposeArr[a][i] = "other results";
                    }    
                }
        }
```

Filters consist of 24 array object as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Inside filters[i].$4 is where i will determine what the data are referring, if its "SUM" , I will call it success, if its not "SUM" i will append the default data given:

[image]

Inside filters[i].$9 is a nested array , only if filters[i].$4 i SUM , it is not a nested array

[image]

The 2d array result should be some like

```
            [Column1      | Column2      | Column3Sum]
            [other result | other result | success]
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve/goal. What type of object is available inside filters?

Comment: Can you show what your input and what you desire to output, i tried my best to see what you are trying to do, but i cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
  transposeArr[i][a] = "Success";
```

I guess you should replace the position of i and a, every where you are doing  transposeArr[a][i]